# Spring MVC method vs Spring MVC Rest Method

Tags: spring, rest, model-view-controller, methods

What is the difference between a Spring MVC method and Spring MVC Rest Method?

Comment: Basically nothing, they are both request handling methods.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC is part of Spring framework to make a Model-View-Controller. When you use it you have the choice to handle RESTful url or not.

Here is a good post to understand what is a RESTful service : https://stackoverflow.com/a/671132/3425744

Here you can find examples to make RESTful service with Spring MVC :

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
- http://www.programming-free.com/2014/01/spring-mvc-40-restful-web-services.html